# Have mouse over rather than text symbol

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a code here that inputs the text you click on into a textbox below.

http://jsfiddle.net/gQms9/6/

But the issue is that it doesnt do a mouse over, it just shows the text symbol.

Why is that is there any way to fix or change that? Or make it clickable like a link without the text symbol when you hover over it?

```
  <style type='text/css'>
    #navlist {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#navlist li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 0px;
    color: #b7b7b7;
}
#navlist li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #b7b7b7;
}
#navlist li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #b7b7b7;
}

  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('a.linkInsert').click(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#linkText').val($(this).data('value'));
    });
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
          <ul id="navlist">
          <li><a class="linkInsert" data-value="1">Link (email &amp; IM)</a></li>
          &nbsp;|&nbsp;
          <li><a class="linkInsert" data-value="2">Direct Link (email &amp; IM)</a></li>
          &nbsp;|&nbsp;
          <li><a class="linkInsert" data-value="3">HTML Image (websites / blogs)</a></li>
          </br>
          <li><a class="linkInsert" data-value="4">HTML Link (websites / blogs)</a></li>
          &nbsp;|&nbsp;
          <li><a class="linkInsert" data-value="5">Message Boards</a></li>
        </ul>
        <input id="linkText" />

</body>
```

Comment: *it doesnt do a mouse over* means what?

Comment: I believe he's referring to the cursor... the pointer versus the text cursor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no pointer icon because you don't have an `href` attribute associated with the `<a>`. You can add one such as `href="#"` or you can add a css rule:

```
#navlist li a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Wow i had no idea that was possible. Awesome this answered my question.

Comment: Actually he should use `href` with [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: If it's not a link, there is no reason to use an `<a>`. Use a span or button tag and then add the above cursor CSS.

Comment: @Mr.Alien He is already using the preventDefault() method, so adding an `href` attribute would be ok.

Comment: @ginovva320 that's what am saying, he should use `href="#"`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Actually his explanation went really weird with the question

Comment: @ginovva320 - Instead of changing the cursor to pointer with CSS, changing the `href` to `#` might be better because so that mobile devices can recognize it as a clickable node.

Answer (score 1):

```
#navlist li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 0px;
    color: #b7b7b7;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gQms9/15/

Comment: lil late for the party huh?

Comment: @Mr.Alien It's Ok. We are here to help others with best answers as we can.

Comment: If that's so than +1 :)